# I cannot type some Khmer vowel on ubuntu OS

Tags: 14.04, language-support

I am new to Ubuntu. When I try to use Khmer language on Ubuntu 14, I face a problem with some vowel I cannot type and it just show "?" or other symbol instead. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: open terminal, run `dpkg -s fonts-khmeros`

Comment: it show :  ``` dpkg-query: package 'fonts-khmeros' is not installed and no information is available```

Comment: what are you trying to type into? the terminal? some program?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing `fonts-khmeros`. By default, I think you only get `fonts-khmeros-core` (that's what I have, and I'm not even sure where Khmer is spoken) which is probably a subset of all the possible Khmer fonts. Also, ensure that you've selected a Khmer font in whatever program you're using.